# Use Values from Raster Statistics (e.g. sum of all cells) in Raster Calculator

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I need to do calculations on raster layers which require the sum of all cells of the raster. I've used the zonal statistics tool for that but it gets a little annoying to do those extra steps (run the plugin, open the Attribute table, copy the sum...).

Is there a way I can calculate and use the values of raster statistics directly inside a raster calculator?

Even better would be to calculate those values from a raster created in the same step:

> A*B*C / Sum (A*B*C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A calculation like

```
A*B*C / Sum (A*B*C)
```

will perform the `A*B*C` operation twice.  To avoid that duplicate effort instead do it in two steps

```
X = A*B*C
X / Sum(X)
```

Storing `A*B*C` has an immediate payoff.  To implement the `Sum` operation, use a zonal summary operator with the entire raster as the zone.  That requires placing a constant, non-null value at every non-null cell of the raster. A simple way to accomplish this is to equate the raster with itself, thus:

```
ZonalSum(X, X==X)
```

(The syntax for `ZonalSum` will depend on the platform and the version of the software.)

The full workflow therefore is

```
X = A*B*C
X / ZonalSum(X, X==X)
```

Comment: This sounds interesting, can you help me out with the "ZonalSum" tool? How can I use it/ where can I find more information? Would that only be possible writing an own script? I use QGIS 2.4 on Windows 8...

Comment: A [search of our site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=qgis%20zonal) turns up a lot of information about that.

Comment: Hey, my comment was a little quick, now I already researched quite a bit but i'm not familiar enough with python and programming in general that I could understand most of the posts. Thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Why not just open the Attribute Table (VAT) and multiply all the values times all the counts ?

Comment: This is a good solution when the raster actually has a VAT ( which occurs only when it has integral values) and when a value is not needed "directly inside a raster calculator," as requested in this thread.